# How do you handle associations between aggregates in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm still wrapping my head around DDD, and one of the stumbling blocks I've encountered is in how to handle associations between separate aggregates. Say I've got one aggregate encapsulating Customers and another encapsulating Shipments.

For business reasons Shipments are their own aggregates, and yet they need to be explicitly tied to Customers. Should my Customer domain entity have a list of Shipments? If so, how do I populate this list at the repository level - given I'll have a CustomerRepository and a ShipmentRepository (one repo per aggregate)?

I'm saying 'association' rather than 'relationship' because I want to stress that this is a domain decision, not an infrastructure one - I'm designing the system from the model first.

Edit: I know I don't need to model tables directly to objects - that's the reason I'm designing the model first. At this point I don't care about the database at all - just the  associations between these two aggregates.

Comment: ddd is that not the gnu tool http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/ ? since when does ddd stand for domain-driven-design ???

Comment: @ Johan - a while, now -- http://domaindrivendesign.org/

Comment: @Erik, well things change and so do the short versions of the long words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason your ShipmentRepository can't aggregate customer data into your shipment models. Repositories do not have to have a 1-to-1 mapping with tables.

I have several repositories which combine multiple tables into a single domain model.

Comment: So are you saying that it's okay to have the same exact data accessible via two different aggregate roots?

Answer (score 5):

I think there's two levels of answering this question. At one level, the question is how do I populate the relationship between customer and shipment.  I really like the  "fill" semantics where your shipment repository can have a fillOrders( List customers, ....).

The other level is "how do I handle the denormalized domain models that are a part of DDD". And "Customer" is probably the best example of them all, because it simply shows up in such a lot of different contexts; almost all your processes have customer in them and the context of the customer is usually extremely varied. At max half the time you are interested in the "orders". If my understanding of the domain was perfect when starting, I'd *never* make a customer domain concept. But it's not, so I always end up making the Customer object. I still remember the project where I after *3 years* felt that I was able to make the proper "Customer" domain model. I *would* be looking for the alternate and more detailed concepts that also represent the customer; PotentialCustomer, OrderingCustomer, CustomerWithOrders and probably a few others; sorry the names aren't better. I'll need some more time for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Shipment has relation many-to-one relationship with Customer.
If your are looking for the shipments of a client, add a query to your shipment repository that takes a client parameter.

In general, I don't create one-to-mane associations between entities when the many side is not limited.